# Permission Denied in Jenkins "Execute shell" step

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jenkins, permission-denied

I'm getting:

```
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36mtest[m: [1;31mError while storing the mojo status[m: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/e2e-tests/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied) -> [1m[Help 1][m
```

in an "Execute Shell" script (mvn test) in a Jenkins job.

I see that the **/var/lib/jenkins/workspace** folder has "drwxr-x---  3 jenkins   jenkins" permission. If I get it right, only jenkins user can write in this folder. However if I put "who" in the shell script, I see that the job is executed as **root** (even though in **/etc/default/jenkins** I see JENKINS_USER=jenkins).

To resolve the 'permission denied' problem I did:

`chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace`

Is this the proper solution? Is it normal for the job to be run as root and not jenkins?

Thanks,
Dinko

Comment: root doesnt need permission to write to a folder. it is the superuser. and never give 777 perms. jenkins shouldnt be running is as root. my thought is that root is creating some folder structure and a jenkins user is getting permission denied because it is root owned. this is very likely an issue with how you deployed jenkins.

Comment: that being said. you didnt supply enough information to really give an educated answer.

Comment: Thanks @ptierno. I installed Jenkins via sudo apt-get install jenkins, no fancy stuff. Which folder structure are you referring to? The /var/lib/jenkins/workspace is jenkins owned, and it is there where I get permission denied.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /var/lib/jenkins/workspace`. Is this a pipeline script or traditional freestyle project? Is the job being executed in a docker container?

Comment: also, create a job just doing a simple `echo "$JENKINS_USER` and supply the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ptierno for helping out on this. The output of the ls command is "drwxrwxrwx 4 jenkis jenkins 4096 Mar 10 18:45 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/". That's due to chmod 777 I did before. That's a traditional freestyle project with a single "mvn test" execute shell step. There's no docker installed on this host, so I suppose no docker involved here. The echo $JENKINS_USER yields no output. Executing "who" in the shell script step outputs "root".

Comment: Just to let you know - rebooting the Jenkins host solved the problem. I reverted to normal permission 0710, not 777 before the reboot. Not sure what the problem was, solved now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the permissions on the **/var/lib/jenkins/workspace** back to **drwxr-x---**, rebooted the Jenkins host and restarted the job. No "Permission Denied" error was logged anymore.

Rebooting the host did solve the issue.